# Generating heat map in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am working on heat map in seaborn.
I have an issue here. I have a football pitch and I draw heat map on the pitch using seaborn using x and y coordinates.
When I plot it, the shape of heat map is out of the background plot as follow

[image]

My pitch drawing is as follow:

[image]

I checked my data that  Ymax is 100 and xMax is 200 in my coordinate system.

As you can see the axes, Xmax is greater than 200 and Ymax is about 120.
How can I draw the heat map to fit to the background football pitch.

The code I used for heat map is as follow:

```
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)  

sns.kdeplot(data["Xstart"],data["Ystart"], cmap="Reds", shade=True,n_levels=40)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(0, 200)
```

Your advice would be much appreciated.
Second question is that I want to use the following color map in seaborn kdeplot

[image]

Thanks,
Zep

Comment: Can you provide code you have so far?

Comment: Hi Martyna,
Thanks for the reply and I have updated it in the question.

Comment: When are you drawing the pitch? ylim/xlim should work fine. But maybe you're overwriting it later on?
As for colors see cmaps: https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html is 'yet' you're looking for? Also to make more shading levels you can increase n_levels

Comment: I cannot test it without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but maybe you need to use the `clip=` argument to [`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot)

Comment: I got it solved. The issue is. Axis equal