# How to plot a heatmap on x-y plane?

Tags: python, heatmap

I create this dataframe (attached) (which has 3 columns, x location, y location, and performance ratio for different systems) and I am trying to make a heatmap regarding to x-y values as a points on x-y coordinates and the last column as the value for the heatmap.

I have tried this:
hm = sns.kdeplot(inv_positions['x'] , inv_positions['y'], shade = True).
but since this function only takes two columns I can not plot the values column on x-y plane.

Any ideas how to do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEyuA.png)

Comment: See here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Joooeey's comment provides a good example using a different method; here is another question more specifically using the same library as you: [Generating heat map in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922674/generating-heat-map-in-seaborn)